# Pie-chart and legend are overlapping

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a pie-chart, like [here](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~laura/pie.png), but the legend and the actual pie are overlapping.

The code I used is here:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

par(mai = c(1,1,1,1))

numb <- c(41, 30, 21, 8)
colors <- c("black", "grey70", "grey30","white")

numb_labels <- round(numb/sum(numb) * 100, 1)
numb_labels <- paste(numb_labels, "%", sep="")
xx <- c("the process of familiarizing with the codebase",
        "the patch review process",
        "the impact on the users of the project",
        "high degree visibility of the contributions")

pie(numb, col=colors, labels=numb_labels, clockwise=TRUE)

legend("top", legend = xx, fill=colors, bty="n")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: as far as I can tell `grid` and `ggplot2` are red herrings -- everything here appears to be base R, you shouldn't need to load those packages (should be harmless though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you attach `ggplot2`.

You can use `layout`:

```
par(mai = c(0,0,0,0))
layout(c(1,2),heights=c(0.3,1))
plot.new()
legend("bottom", legend = xx, fill=colors, bty="n")
pie(numb, col=colors, labels=numb_labels, clockwise=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use argument `xpd=TRUE` with function `par()` and then set legend outside the plot region with coordinates of legend.

```
par(xpd=TRUE)
pie(numb, col=colors, labels=numb_labels, clockwise=TRUE)
legend(-1.4,1.6, legend = xx, fill=colors, bty="n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
par(mai = c(1,1,4,1), xpd=TRUE)
pie(numb, col=colors, labels=numb_labels, clockwise=TRUE)
legend("top", inset=c(0,-0.5),cex=0.9,legend = xx, fill=colors, bty="n")
```

Note: First element of inset shift your legend horizontally and the second one vertically. 
cex parameter can resize your legend. So may adjust your legend by changing those parameter values.